# Subtract row values of 2 columns within same table in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to subtract the row values of 2 different columns in the same table.

**Table schema**

```
--------------------------------------------
id | com  | type | refund | support | status
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1.17 | res  | 0.00   | NULL    | 0
2  | 3.00 | sys  | 1.85   | 12      | 1
3  | 4.00 | sys  | 0.00   | NULl    | 0
4  | 8.00 | par  | 2.00   | 28      | 1
```

I want to subtract `com` - `refund` if `support` column `is not NULL` and `status = 1`

**Output** should be like as

```
------------
id | output 
------------
2  | 1.15 |
4  | 6.00 |
```

Comment: Simply do the com - refund  subtraction in the SELECT list, and use a WHERE clause to get "if support column is not NULL and status = 1".

Comment: Do it in steps. 1) `select * from tablename`.

Comment: 2) Add WHERE clause.

Comment: 3) Add subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, (COM - REFUND) AS OUTPUT
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE SUPPORT IS NOT NULL AND STATUS = 1;
```

The 'as output' names the column in your result set. The where statement filters out your rows by the conditions you have given. The FROM clause tells on which table to execute the query. You have to put your own table name.